# Z3-solver throws 'model is not available' exception on python 3

Tags: z3, python-3.5, z3py, sat

For solving a SAT-problem I decided to use the Z3-solver from Microsoft and Python 3. The aim is to take a long model (up to 500,000 features) and find all possible solutions. To find them I want to add the first solution S1 to the initial equation and exclude S1 it and so forth. I will do it using a while-loop.
Solving a SAT-problem is important for me, because I wanna analyse feature models.

But I'm facing a problem with adding sth to the initial equation. I will share a minimal example:

```
# Import statements
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0,'/.../z3/bin')
from z3 import *        # https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki

def main():

    '''
    Solves after transformation a given boolean equation by using the Z3-Solver from Microsoft.
    '''

    fd = dict()
    fd['_r'] = Bool('_r')
    fd['_r_1'] = Bool('_r_1')

    equation = '''And(fd.get("_r"),Or(Not(fd.get("_r")),fd.get("_r_1")))'''

    # Solve the equation
    s = Solver()
    exec('s.add(' + equation + ')')
    s.check()
    print(s.model())

    ###################################
    # Successfull until here.
    ###################################

    s.add(Or(fd['_r'] != bool(s.model()[fd.get('_r')])))
    # s.add(Or(fd['_r'] != False))

    s.check()
    print(s.model())


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The first coded line after `# Successfull...` throws an `z3types.Z3Exception: model is not available` error. So i tried the line above adding simply `false` to the model. That works just fine.

I'm stucked here. I believe the error is easy to solve, but I don't see the solution. Does one of you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Models become available only after s.check() returns 'sat'.
The model maps Boolean propositions to {True, False} and 
generally maps constants and functions to fixed values. 
The requirement is that the model provides an interpretation
that satisfies the formula that is added to the solver 's'.
We don't know whether the solver state is satisfiable before
we have called 's.check()'.

Suppose you want to say:

```
s.add(Or(fd['_r'] != bool(s.model()[fd.get('_r')])))
```

meaning that in the model that satisfies the constraint should
have the property that if '_r' is true under the model, then
fd['_r'] != True, and if '_r' is false under the model, then
fd['_r'] != False. This is equivalent to saying
fd['_r'] != '_r'. So it isn't really necessary to access the value
of '_r' in whatever model may evaluate '_r' in order to say something
about the evaluation of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You cleared my mind about the description of the problem I gave here as an example. Thanks for explaining why my example can't work out.